How do I change the clang library path?
I'm using apple clang++ to make a geometryjump mod, but while compile, I got two errors, they said that the CMake build files were unable to find <algorithm> and <cerrno> in #include statements. These are both built in C++ librarys. I was not able to find anyone else who has ever had this problem before.
I figured out the error was that there was a bunch of paths that contained usr/local/... in them near the end of the path string, but I don't have any usr/local/... paths. Instead it should just be usr/... paths. I never have found out why I don't have any usr/local paths.
I am on MacOS Sequoia 15.0.1

Any help with this would be appreciated.
I tried compiling my program and was not expecting it to give this error.
Edit: I forgot to specify that I am using VSCode CMake extention and Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3).

Did you enable c++11 or better in your CMakeLists.txt?

This kind of problem (compilers failing to find standard header files) only ever seem to happen on Macs. What is it about MacOS that causes these problems? Just curious, I have no experience of Macs myself.

Your problem description is too vague. You are better to provide [mcve] which demonstrates your problem.

My guesses would be either one or both of a stale cmake cache or not having reinstalled the xcode command line tools after doing an OS update

@john it's a specific bug of the command line tools being broken by OS updates (and xcode in general not being forward compatible with new OS versions). The intended usage would be for people to just use xcode and it'll warn about issues when you run it after a breaking os update, people using the command line tools on their own get no such help

@drescherjm I am using Clang 16

@Tsyvarev I provided more details now

Have you tried running CMake manually? usually with VSCode's cmake extension you have to first remove cmake_cache folder and then try running CMake manually. Run this and see what happens cmake -B build -S .

Also note that you should use clang++ for c++ source codes and clang for c source codes. This should solve your problem

I solved it awhile ago, but i don't know how to close a question ¯_(ツ)_/¯
